# Sound recording from website using Chrome for IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome

So I have a site where I can record the users audio. This works on the following:

- Safari
- Safari IOS
- Chrome Desktop
- MS edge Desktop
- Safari Desktop
- Etc...

More or less every device however when using the `chrome browser` on an `iPhone` I am unable to get access to the `microphone`.

Does anyone know why? Is there a limitation on this specific app on iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your microphone for features in Chrome, like Voice Search.

1. On your iPhone or iPad, open the Chrome app.
2. Go to a site that wants to use your microphone.
3. When prompted, tap **Allow** or Block.

> If you’ve turned off microphone or camera access, you can turn on your
>   mic or camera permissions in your device settings.

*[From official chrome help center.](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2693767?co=GENIE.Platform%3DiOS&hl=en)*

Comment: The prompt is not shown for me when requesting permissions... All other browser work.

Comment: Have you checked your device settings??

Comment: iOS -> Settings App -> Chrome there is no audio permission option.
iOS -> Settings App -> Privacy -> Microphone There is no entry for Chrome and also Chrome did not ask for microphone permissions on the first visit. 
I tested this on two different iPhones.